# C# The exit message box pops up twice. I want to generate an event once.

Tags: c#, wpf, messagebox

```
bool ClosedFormMenu = false;

    private void Cancel_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult dialog = MessageBox.Show("Do you really want to close the program?", "program close", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
        if(dialog == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            ClosedFormMenu = true;
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }

    private void Form_closing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult dialog = MessageBox.Show("Do you really want to close the program?", "program close", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);

        if(!ClosedFormMenu)
        {
            if (dialog == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                Application.Exit();
            }
            else if (dialog == DialogResult.No)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                return;
            }
        }

    }
```

Press the X or Cancel button to display the exit message. Press 'Yes' on the message and it will appear again. I want to eliminate this phenomenon.
I would like to implement the program so that it will exit completely if I click cancel button or X button.
Answer Thanks in advance.
Thank you.

Comment: in your event handler shouldnt `DialogResult dialog = MessageBox.Show("Do you really want to close the program?", "program close", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
` be in your if condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling Application.Exit() from the button handler also calls Form_closing(). Having the dialog box in both the button handler and Form_closing() makes the question appear twice.  Try this:

```
private void Cancel_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Application.Exit();
}

private void Form_closing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult dialog = MessageBox.Show("Do you really want to close the program?", "program close", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);

    if (dialog == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        e.Cancel = false;
    }
    else
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Why `else if` if you know that it can be either `Yes` or `No`, there's no third condition? You should just `if else` here. Or, even better, `e.Cancel = dialog == DialogResult.No`

Comment: Firstly, because the OP already had it in his/her post and the problem wasn't related to it.  Secondly, semantics, I'd say.  I use it myself to avoid any uncertainty on the default state of `e.Cancel` when I or somebody else read the code later.  But you're right: It can of course be omitted if you want to.

Comment: Press X and press Yes in the message box to exit the program, but it will not exit in the background. I want to solve this.

Comment: You're getting the dialog, the window is closing, but the application is still running?  Then you have some thread still running somewhere.  Are you using a timer perhaps?

Comment: Can you describe your situation better?  Is the window being closed, and you have to press the Stop Debugging button in Visual Studio to shut down the application?  I'm pretty sure something's running in the background that you've forgotten to close down then.  A serial port perhaps?

Comment: Break the application, and open the Threads window (Debug>Windows>Threads) to get an overview of the running threads.  It'll show you what's running in the background.

Comment: Not sure what you mean here.  But something is definitely blocking your application from closing down.  But without more information about the nature of your application I can't help you.

Answer (score 3):

As soon as you call Application.Exit(), the event method Form_closing() will be called.
This is why your MessageBox appears twice.

You call it in the Cancel method, exit out of the application, the application calls Form_Closing() and the MessageBox appears again.

You should only call

```
Application.Exit();
```

in your Cancel_btn_Click Method.

---

You can reduce your code to the following:

```
private void Cancel_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Application.Exit();
}

private void Form_closing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult dialog = MessageBox.Show("Do you really want to close the program?", "program close", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);

    if (dialog == DialogResult.No)
        e.Cancel = true;
    // TODO: Add 'else' if you want to call a cleanup
    // method or do something before the application closes.
}
```

---

**Why is 'return' missing in Form_closing()?**

'return' is missing, because this is a method with the return type 'void'.
It is not expected to 'return' anything and since we do not need to exit out of the method prematurely, we do not need it.

**Why is 'Application.Exit()' missing in Form_closing()?**

The application has already received the command to exit. This is why it is closing the form. Therefor, we do not need it here.

Comment: Press X and press Yes in the message box to exit the program, but it will not exit in the background. I want to solve this.

Comment: Then something is stopping the application from exiting. Are you doing anything in the background? Perhaps you have a thread open and it is waiting for it to end before closing?

Comment: Yes, You must kill the process in Task Manager to complete the shutdown.

Comment: Try to open your application in Debug Mode. After 'exiting' the application, press pause and try to check where it is stuck. Without more code, i'm not sure i can find out what is causing this. Perhaps you can open a new question with more specific information to this new problem?